# Suppose $a_n \ge 0$ for all n and that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ converges, does the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ also converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

I don't think so, but I'm not sure as to how to prove this so. A counterexample I can think of is for $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, here $a_n \ge 0$ for all *n* and its infinite series when squared does converge. But $a_n$ does not converge, it diverges.

Comment: That's it : you've proven that the statement in the title is false!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the counter-example that $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.